# phoneGap - iOS - images OK with wifi, but not loaded using 3G (work fine using safari)

Tags: ios, image, cordova, uiwebview, 3g

I'm encountering a strange behavior - the (remotely hosted) images of my app are not showing up only in this situation:

- loaded using 3G
- on an iPhone
- using `phonegap`

The images load okay when:

- I launch the app. with wifi (even from an hotspot)
- I launch the website version of the app (with mobile safari)
- I use an android + 3G

I've done several searches on Google but found nothing about that case.
(The images are remotely hosted on a public IP, accessible using 3G, the android version of my app proves it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue was because "SFR" (a 3G french provider) used a NAT, all the http calls was made to an "SFR"'s IP with the real url hidden in the url's parameters, the only solution was to deactived the white filtering of the domain names and to allow *

Comment: Hi Bruno, I have the same problem with SFR. Can you give more infos about how to "deactived the white filtering of the domain names and to allow *" ? Thanks.

Comment: you'll find the doc here : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html