# Strange situation when loading an image using the cell phone data plan, but all works fine over WiFi

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, wifi

Ok this is somehow troublesome, and I'm about to give up on this.
I have an application for Windows Phone that summarizes a popular news site, I show the main news and some pictures galleries that the site has. It has been working ok for several months, until I started noticing some bad comments about the app.
When I checked the application using my Wi-Fi (or any other hot spot) it works all right, all the images from both, the news and galleries show ok.
But when I use the cell phone data plan, the images just wont load, and I mean, If I add an image from another site, it will load it just fine, but not the ones from the news site I'm trying to get.

an example would be the image form http://i.televisa.com/noticieros/fotos/1311/08/RobertoBarreda.jpg/_jcr_content/renditions/cq5dam.thumbnail.624.351.jpg, it loads ok if I use the Wi-Fi, but not my cell phone data plan.

And to verify this, I've created a simple app that only does this:

```
            <Image Source="http://i.televisa.com/noticieros/fotos/1311/08/RobertoBarreda.jpg/_jcr_content/renditions/cq5dam.thumbnail.624.351.jpg"></Image>
```

If anyone has an explanation/solution I would really appreciate it. Thanks!.

Comment: The problem seems to be similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309489/phonegap-ios-images-ok-with-wifi-but-not-loaded-using-3g-work-fine-using-s

Comment: Thank you, Will check how can I bypass the 3G provider filter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Image's Opened, Failed and Progress changed event handlers to debug the issue and you can use emulator's feature of changing n/w types too